# Extract email from website with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to extract 2 things from this website: https://bazasklepowinternetowych.pl/dekoracje-happenings-pl/

First: "https://happenings.pl" from "ADRES STRONY: https://happenings.pl". It's a H3

Second: "info@happenings.pl" from "Email: info@happenings.pl". It's a "li" element

How to fetch it with IMPORTXML into Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch anything online by copying the xpath and pasting in the google sheets `importxml` formula:

- info@happenings.pl: `=importxml("https://bazasklepowinternetowych.pl/dekoracje-happenings-pl/", "/html/body/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/strong")`

In order to copy the xpath, you can:

- right click the element you want in the webpage
- inspect element
- right click the highlighted element you want to target
- copy
- xpath
- paste xpath in the formula, and change the ticks (`'`) with quotation marks (`"`)

[image]